# Proof of Weierstrass Theorem from Rudin's-Multiple questions though the proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, polynomials

I am studying Stone-Weierstrass theorem. I am not understanding well and I have a multiple point that I need some help to have better understanding.

1. In the proof, he set $Q_n(x)=C_n (1-x^2)^2$ then $\int _{-1} ^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx \ge 2\int _{0} ^{1/{\sqrt{n}}} (1-x^2)^n \ge 2\int _{0} ^{1/{\sqrt{n}}} (1-n{x^2})dx$
   I don't understand why $(1-x^2)^n \ge (1-n{x^2})$.
   I understand that the inequality holds but I don't understand how this idea can come up.
2. And there is a part that change of variable is applied according to his explanation but I don't really understand how he got it.
   We have $P_n(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}f(x+t)Q_{n}(t)dt$, where $(0 \le x \le 1)$.
   Then $P_n(x)=\int_{-x}^{1-x}f(x+t)Q_{n}(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)Q_{n}(t-x)dt$. 
   I don't understand the process and I don't understand how we can conclude $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial.

I think understanding in these two parts would help me understand the whole proof.

Comment: Even though this is an old post - I'm commenting for future reference. Rudin comments on the next page how to get the inequality in (1). He says to consider, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and each $x\in[0,1]$, the function $F_{n}(x)=(1-x^{2})^{n}-1+nx^{2}$. Note, $F_{n}(0)=0=F_{n}(1)$. $F_{n}$ is continuous on $[0,1)$, and, on $(0,1)$ we have $F_{n}'(x)=2nx(1-x^{2})^{n-1}+2nx$. Clearly, $F_{n}'(x)>0$ on $(0,1)$, so $F$ is increasing on $[0,1)$. Overall $F_{n}(x)\geq 0$ on $[0,1]$, and the inequality easily follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can prove $(1-x^2)^n \ge 1-nx^2$ by induction.
2. Let $k=x+t$. (I am just calling it $k$, use any other letter besides $x$ or $t$.) Then $t=k-x$. Also, at $t=-x$, we have $k=x+(-x)=0$. At $t=1-x$, we have $k=x+(1-x)=1$. Thus, $$\int_{-x}^{1-x} f(x+t) Q_n(t) \, dt = \int_0^1 f(k) Q_n (k-x) \, dk=\int_0^1 f(t) Q_n (t-x) \, dt.$$
   For the right-most equality, replace $k$ with $t$. The value of the definite integral will not change.

Comment: For point $2$, he's wondering why $P_n$ is a polynomial, not $Q_n$. The answer comes from the expression $$\int_0^1 f(t) Q_n (t-x) \, dt.$$ If $Q_n(z)=\sum a_i z^i$ then this integral will end up being a sum of powers of $z$ with coefficients the integral of $c_i f(t)t^i$ over $[0,1]$ for some appropriate $c_i$. More simply, the integral $$\int_0^1 f(t)(t-x)^j dt$$ is always a polynomial in $x$, and we're summing many of those.

Comment: Have you actually proven 1 with induction? It looks quite tedious.

Comment: @AlexH. Yes, but I want to leave it to the OP as a hint.

Answer (score 2):

For 1., just look at $x >0  \mapsto (1-x)^n$ and its second derivative. You will see that it's convex and hence "above its tangent" at $x=0$.

For 2., start by thinking of the case $Q_n(u) = u^k$. If you expand $Q_n(x-t)$, you have a polynomial expression in $x$ and $t$. After multiplication by $f(t)$ and integration on $t$, you're left with a polynomial expression in $x$.

Another angle on 2., if you know the rules of derivation under the integral sign, you instantly see that if $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$, the $(n+1)$-th derivative of your integral $P_n(x)$ is nil, which proves it is also a polynomial.